# How do I correcly handle ZoneLocalMapping.ResultType.Ambiguous?

Tags: c#, nodatime

In my code I try to handle ZoneLocalMapping.ResultType.Ambiguous. The line

```
unambiguousLocalDateTime = localDateTimeMapping.EarlierMapping;
```

throws an InvalidOperationException with message "EarlierMapping property should not be called on a result of type Ambiguous".

I have no clue how I should handle it. Can you give me an example?

This is what my code looks like:

```
public Instant getInstant(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute)
{
        var localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute); //invalidated, might be not existing
        var timezone = DateTimeZone.ForId(TimeZoneId); //TimeZone is set elsewhere, example "Brazil/East"
        var localDateTimeMapping = timezone.MapLocalDateTime(localDateTime);
        ZonedDateTime unambiguousLocalDateTime;
        switch (localDateTimeMapping.Type)
        {
            case ZoneLocalMapping.ResultType.Unambiguous: 
                unambiguousLocalDateTime = localDateTimeMapping.UnambiguousMapping;
                break;
            case ZoneLocalMapping.ResultType.Ambiguous:
                unambiguousLocalDateTime = localDateTimeMapping.EarlierMapping;
                break;
            case ZoneLocalMapping.ResultType.Skipped: 
                unambiguousLocalDateTime = new ZonedDateTime(localDateTimeMapping.ZoneIntervalAfterTransition.Start, timezone);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unexpected mapping result type: {0}", localDateTimeMapping.Type));
        }
        return unambiguousLocalDateTime.ToInstant();
}
```

If I look at class ZoneLocalMapping I see the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// In an ambiguous mapping, returns the earlier of the two ZonedDateTimes which map to the original LocalDateTime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">The mapping isn't ambiguous.</exception>
    public virtual ZonedDateTime EarlierMapping { get { throw new InvalidOperationException("EarlierMapping property should not be called on a result of type " + type); } }
```

That's why I am receiving the exception, but what should I do to get the EarlierMapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a relatively old build. `ZoneLocalMapping` has changed a bit since then, and I suspect I've fixed the bug you've found. Here's an example which works:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Program
{    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var local = new LocalDateTime(2012, 10, 28, 1, 30, 0);
        var zone = DateTimeZone.ForId("Europe/London");
        var mapping = zone.MapLocal(local);

        Console.WriteLine(mapping.Count); // 2
        Console.WriteLine(mapping.First()); // 1.30 with offset +1
        Console.WriteLine(mapping.Last()); // 1.30 with offest +0
    }    
}
```

Your actual method can go away entirely now, due to the improved "resolver" API. You can now use:

```
private static readonly ZoneLocalResolver CustomResolver =
    Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(Resolvers.ReturnEarlier,
                                    Resolvers.ReturnStartOfIntervalAfter);

...

Instant instant = zone.ResolveLocal(localDateTime, CustomResolver).ToInstant();
```

Comment: (At this moment) the latest source can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/checkout